# Measuring depth or height from sea level

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

How is the depth or height relative to sea level measured? Well, if it's near the ocean, it can be easily measured manually, but what if it is 100 km away from the sea? What method is used?

Comment: These days it's measured with GPS. In the old days you'd survey the ground to establish the difference in height relative to some known reference point.

Comment: For some applications (especially where GPS signal is lost : underwater, caves,... or where cost/energy matters), the atmospheric pressure is still widely used. For good accuracy, it should be compensated for pressure variations measured at a known point.

Comment: It's a famous problem http://www.science20.com/news_articles/what_happens_bridge_when_one_side_uses_mediterranean_sea_level_and_another_north_sea-121600

Answer (score 2):

Orography has already been discussed, but it still leaves the question of how bathymetry is measured. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathymetry#Measurement):

> Satellites are also used to measure bathymetry. Satellite radar maps deep-sea topography by detecting the subtle variations in sea level caused by the gravitational pull of undersea mountains, ridges, and other masses. On average, sea level is higher over mountains and ridges than over abyssal plains and trenches.